# How do I install the ray-tracing application POV-Ray on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I'm surprised (and disappointed) to see that the classic ray-tracing program povray has been dropped from the repositories on 12.04. What is the best way to install it? It doesn't appear that anyone has prepared a PPA for precise.

Comment: [POV-Ray is now released under the Affero GPL](http://povray.org/povlegal.html), so it will probably return to the repositories within a few releases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### licensing

From the povray [distribution license](http://www.povray.org/distribution-license.html) is not a GPL2+ or 3+ license that normally is the requirement for incorporation into the main ubuntu repositories.

Indeed - [debian classify](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=povray) this as *non-free* - although why this package was not made available into *multiverse*, I'm not sure.

#### compiling

It's actually very simple to compile this command line application from [source](http://www.povray.org/download/):

First install some prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now download the source-code:

```
wget http://www.povray.org/redirect/www.povray.org/ftp/pub/povray/Official/Unix/povray-3.6.tar.gz

tar -zxvf povray-3.6.tar.gz
cd povray-3.6.1
```

Now configure it:

```
./configure COMPILED_BY="yourname <youremail@somewhere.com>"
```

N.B. use your email address.

Next - compile and install:

```
make
sudo make install
```

#### for the uninitiated...

This is an example output

save the contents from here as [povpawn.pov](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/x_sam/geo/povpawn.pov)

Now run povray

```
povray +Ipovpawn.pov
```

This will create a file in your folder called `povpawn.png`

[image]

More information from the povray website:

- http://www.povray.org/documentation/

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work anymore because the archive is no longer hosted at povray.org - look at the github answer below.

Comment: @CatherineHolloway: The old version is still available, the URL is http://www.povray.org/redirect/www.povray.org/ftp/pub/povray/Old-Versions/Official-3.62/Linux/povlinux-3.6.tgz. It's already compiled and should work out of the box. Use the contained `install` command (via `sudo`) to install it.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the newest POV-Ray version from [github](https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray):

**Get the source code**

```
git clone https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray.git
```

**Install required packages**

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg8-dev libtiff5-dev libopenexr-dev
```

**Configure, Make, Install**

```
cd unix/
./prebuild.sh
cd ../
./configure COMPILED_BY="your name <email@address>" 
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: On 14.04 64bit, I ran `./configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu COMPILED_BY="my name <my-email-address>"`

Comment: For those who are having boost thread issues when running `./configure`: `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction on the [POv-Ray](http://www.povray.org/download/linux.php) website, and did not encounter much problems during installation.