# POV-Ray - Ubuntu 12.04 file not found

Tags: command-line, software-installation, povray

I have installed POV-Ray on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS box by
following [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156449/how-do-i-install-the-ray-tracing-application-pov-ray-on-12-04)'s post.

It worked fine the first time when I ran the command

```
~$ povray +Ipovpawn.pov
```

but now I get

```
  0:00:00 Parsing
Possible Scene File Parser Initialization Error: Could not find file
'povpawn.pov'
Scene File Parser Initialization Error: Cannot open input file.
Total Scene Processing Times
  Parse Time:    0 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds (0 seconds)
  Photon Time:   0 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds (0 seconds)
  Render Time:   0 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds (0 seconds)
  Total Time:    0 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds (0 seconds)
```

I tried moving `pawn.pov` file from `/home/me/povray-3.6.1` to `/usr/local/share/povray-3.6` and got

```
access denied check povray.conf
```

Comment: If you can post the exact command you used. It is normal that you could not write to `/usr/local/share/` as a normal user, so you may be missing some option.

Comment: Try to post **all** the commands and output of the terminal in just one group. Is not useful show the output and then other output and then the command that return the first output, it is confusing!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is called `pawn.pov` as you say later in the question, then the command you want is

```
povray +Ipawn.pov
```

The command you said in the question has a "pov" too many.

Comment: ummm, turns out I was running the command from the wrong directory.